# Trying to get ADB command in Linux (for copying timestamps) to work with spaces in names

Tags: linux, command-line, android

Using Linux Mint 13, I have been trying to ADB copy files and directories to a connected Android over USB.
Need to preserve the timestamps.

(I am aware that in Unix, only Time Modified is stored).

Got a command from Googling but don't understand it much. Link is below.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35580/how-can-i-transfer-photos-to-my-android-jelly-bean-device-while-preserving-the-o

After adb push "FROM" "ANDROID_PHONE"
I use the command below:

```
find . | while read file; do timestamp_stat=$(stat -c "%y" "$file"); timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S" -d "$timestamp_stat"); echo "$timestamp: $file"; adb shell su -c "touch -t $timestamp \"/sdcard/ANDROID_PHONE\""; done
```

I realise that the above command only manages to use Touch to copy timestamps for filenames and directories with no spaces in them. Get error messages eg. Unknown id: R for those with spaces.

How should I amend the code?

Comment: If you use the `file="$(line)"` instead of `read file`, then `"$file"` will contain any leading or trailing spaces (or other characters, apart from new-lines). If you don't have `line`, you can use the equivalent `head -n 1`. But should you not have `"$file"` in the `adb` call?

Comment: Glanced through the above.. still can't get it to work.

Tried

find . -print0 | while read file;


I guess I don't know enough Linux commands to troubleshoot this..

Comment: I think the problem may be double expansion: your host expands once, and the `adb` shell expands again. I still don't see how the `adb` command is supposed to know which file the `touch` command is supposed to act on; or is there something special about the string `ANDROID_PHONE`? In the past I have mounted the Android as a USB drive, and I have used the normal copy (`cp --preserve=all`) to maintain the time stamps without resorting to `adb`. I now use a file management app in the Android to copy over WiFi, and this also preserves them.

Comment: Hi AFH, thank you for the reply. The issue is that timestamps for files are preserved, but timestamps for directories is not, thus necessitating use of a script/command to "copy over" timestamps.

This script works perfectly for folders or filenames without spaces. I run it from Linux from start of the folder tree I want to compare, and only need to edit the "/sdcard/Download/$file\" part to reflect the Android path I want to compare with.

Mounting an Android as a USB drive requires USB Mass Storage which newer phones no longer have.

Comment: If the `touch` command on the Android should be `touch -t $timestamp "/sdcard/ANDROID_PHONE/$file"` then I can see that the problem is double expansion, but without `"$file"` then I can't follow how it's supposed to work. In passing, I would note that it is unusual to modify directory time-stamps, because they are updated every time an included file or subdirectory is created, deleted or renamed.

Comment: How do you mount the Android as a USB drive in Linux? I was of the impression that as UMS is disabled, only MTP and PTP can be used.

Comment: I did this in Ubuntu 12.10 and I no longer have the files for this, but I found [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702) by searching for "ubuntu mtp mount". I imagine it will be pretty similar for other Debian-derived distributions, but for others you can try searching for your own Linux version.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain part of it:

`find .` is used to list all files and directories in the current path (that is the dot). Find is not told to do anything with the results, but the default behaviour on most find implementations is to print them to std out.

Proper coding would have used a `find /path/to/pictures -ls` or `-print0`. The last is useful when there are non standard characters in the name (e.g. spaces).

The output us the previous command is then forwared to the next part. This is done via the pipe (`|`) symbol.

The next command is wrapped in a while loop (highlighted in bold)

**while read file; do** timestamp_stat=$(stat -c "%y" "$file"); timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S" -d "$timestamp_stat"); echo "$timestamp: $file"; adb shell su -c "touch -t $timestamp \"/sdcard/ANDROID_PHONE\""; **done**

This reads from a file (on in our case from stdin which contains the output of the previous command. The results from reading are stored in a variable named *file*.

(finds -> find's output |  --> input for the while loop)

For each of these results the following set of commands is executed in sequence:

```
timestamp_stat=$(stat -c "%y" "$file");
timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S" -d "$timestamp_stat"); 
echo "$timestamp: $file"; 
adb shell su -c "touch -t $timestamp \"/sdcard/ANDROID_PHONE\"";
```

A variable timestamp created and filled with the results from stat -c
(stat is an utility displays information about the file pointed to by file. In this case the file it points to is stored in $file and wrapped in quoted to avoid problems with spaces.

The results are then replaced by the same information in a different format.

Next this result is echo'd to std out. This is probably so the user has some idea where the script is.

Lastly it does something with abd, with which I have no solid information.  I guess is instructs the android phone to touch a file. Touching a file usually changes the date on a file to the current time. However in this case it specifies which time to set the file.

From the touch manpage:

```
-t      Change the access and modification times to the specified time
        instead of the current time of day.  The argument is of the form
         ``[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]'' where each pair of letters represents
         the following:
```

---

Moving on to a solution:

Sadly non here, just hints:

- Change IFS
- Or use -print0 (and possible with xargs -0)
- Use move the enteire thing into find. Right now find is used to find the files and the results (including spaces) is then passed on to a shell.  Find can do things on its own though. No while readfile is needed. a `find /path/to/files -exec "something" {}  \;` might work better and faster.

Comment: `find <path> -exec <something> {} \;` is in many cases actually slower. That's because it will start `<something>` on every iteration. Many tools can take an arbitrary number of input files, in which case doing `files=$(find <path> -print) && <something> $files` is faster because it only starts `<something>` once.

Comment: True. Sometimes you can work around that by find \+.